# Check if Values of one column in another column of different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I am new to SQL and struck with this below scenario, can any one of you please help on this.

I want to check if the ingredients of a product allowed on production line if so then production line names for the product where it can be produced.

**Table 1**

```
ProductionLine       Allergen
  BB1          Tree nut
  BB1          Peanut
  BB1           Milk
  BB1           Wheat
  BB2          Tree nut
  BB2          Peanut
  BB2           Milk 
  BB2           soy
  BB2           Egg
```

**Table 2**

```
Product                Ingredients
P1                 Tree nut
P1                 Peanut
P1                 Milk 
P1                 soy
```

Here the Product P1 can be produced on BB2 line as all the ingredients are allowed on BB2 Allergen list. so i want to have the result set as

**Expected Result**

```
  Product            Ingredients          ProductionLine
  P1                 Tree nut                 BB2
  P1                 Peanut                   BB2
  P1                 Milk                     BB2   
  P1                 soy                      BB2
```

If any one of the ingredient is not allowed on any line then we can not produce product on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates in either table, you can use a `left join` and `group by`.  The key is counting the number of matches and being sure that it matches the total number of ingredients.

```
select t2.product, t1.productionline
from (select t2.*,
             count(*) over (partition by product) as num_products
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.ingredient = t1.allergen
group by t2.product, t1.productionline, t2.num_products
having count(t1.ingredient) = num_products;
```

Comment: Thanks @gordonlinoff, can you help me to get the result set to include all the columns from both the tables and adding Production line as extra column where the product can be produced.

Comment: if that is not possible to get all together ,at least i would like to have the Ingredients along with product name would be helpful. when i tried to include the ingredients i am getting wrong result set.

Comment: @Naveenvadlamudi . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question.  This answers the question that you have asked here.  That said, you can use `string_agg()` to gather together all the ingredient/allergen values, so that might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So, ideally the Allergen would have some ID that you can join on so you could do something like

```
SELECT Table2.Product, Table2.Ingredients, Table1.ProductionLine FROM Table1.AllergenId JOIN Table2.IngredientAllergenId
```

If your tables aren't structured like this, they probably should be. But if you can't change it, you can do this.

```
SELECT Table2.Product, Table2.Ingredients, Table1.ProductionLine FROM Table1.Allergen JOIN Table2.Allergen
```