# Check if values of one column is in another column

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and struck with this below scenario, can any one of you please help on this.

I want to check if the ingredients of a product allowed on production line if so then production line names for the product where it can be produced.

**Table 1**

```
ProductionLine       Allergen
  BB1          Tree nut
  BB1          Peanut
  BB1           Milk
  BB1           Wheat
  BB2          Tree nut
  BB2          Peanut
  BB2           Milk 
  BB2           soy
  BB2           Egg
```

**Table 2**

```
Product                Ingredients
P1                 Tree nut
P1                 Peanut
P1                 Milk 
P1                 soy
```

Here the Product P1 can be produced on BB2 line as all the ingredients are allowed on BB2 Allergen list. so i want to have the result set as

**Expected Result**

```
  Product            Ingredients          ProductionLine   
  P1                 Tree nut                 BB2                 
  P1                 Peanut                   BB2            
  P1                 Milk                     BB2            
  P1                 soy                      BB2
```

If any one of the ingredient is not allowed on any line then we can not produce product on that line.

**Expected Result**

```
  Product            Ingredients          ProductionLine   
  P1                 Tree nut                 BB2                 
  P1                 Peanut                   BB2            
  P1                 Milk                     BB2            
  P1                 soy                      BB2
```

Code that i have right now

```
select I.[Product Name],I.[Ingredients], F.[Production Line]
from (select I.*,
             count(*) over (partition by [Product Name],[Ingredients]) as num_products
      from [dbo].[ProductIngredients] I
     ) I left join
    [dbo].[ProductionFacilities] F
     on I.[Ingredients] = F.allergen
group by I.[Product Name], F.[Production Line], I.num_products,I.[Ingredients]
having count(F.[Allergen]) = num_products;
```

Comment: What have you tried? I am happy to assist but would like to see what you have attempted first of all.

Comment: here is what i have                            
                                                                                                                     
  select I.[Product Name],I.[Ingredients], F.[Production Line]
from (select I.*,
             count(*) over (partition by [Product Name],[Ingredients]) as num_products
      from [dbo].[ProductIngredients] I
     ) I left join
    [dbo].[ProductionFacilities] F
     on I.[Ingredients] = F.allergen
group by I.[Product Name], F.[Production Line], I.num_products,I.[Ingredients]
having count(F.[Allergen]) = num_products

Comment: Hi @Naveen, please edit the question to include this SQL please.

Comment: @Bruce , i have included the code in question at the bottom as requested.

Comment: You have asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775400/check-if-values-of-one-column-in-another-column-of-different-table and accepted the answer. What is the problem?

Comment: @forpas , the problem is int he result set there is no ingredients column included and when i try to bring in that column , the result i am getting is not correct as expected. it would be really helpful if i can get the ingredients included in the result . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 CTEs to count the number of ingredients for each product and productionline and join to table2:

```
with 
  cte1 as (
    select t2.product, count(*) counter
    from table2 t2 
    group by t2.product
  ),
  cte2 as (
    select t2.product, t1.productionline, count(*) counter
    from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
    on t1.allergen = t2.ingredients
    group by t2.product, t1.productionline
  )
select 
  t2.product, t2.ingredients, c2.productionline
from table2 t2 
inner join cte1 c1 on c1.product = t2.product
inner join cte2 c2 on c2.product = t2.product and c2.counter = c1.counter
order by t2.product, c2.productionline
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d19f66afdf4df5a49ac84603489378af).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*,l.ProductionLine   
FROM table2 p
INNER JOIN (SELECT product,count(*)  AS ingredients_cnt FROM table2 GROUP BY product) pc
ON p.product=pc.product
INNER JOIN table1 l
ON p.ingredients=l.Allergen
GROUP BY p.product,l.ProductionLine
HAVING COUNT(l.Allergen)=pc.ingredients_cnt
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i am getting this below error and when i include the column in group by clause i am not getting any result at all                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                           
 Column 'pc.ingredients_cnt' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause